# Seeking Vehicle Routing Problem and Location-Allocation Tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, location-allocation, qgis-network-analysis

I was wondering if there was a tool in QGIS that is similar to ArcGIS Network Analyst's Vehicle Routing Problem and Location-Allocation tools?

I could not find any info about this in the internet.

Comment: As I know there is no such thing with (advanced) possibilities like ArcGIS Network Analyst for QGIS yet. But things are improving fast.. Check for new network Plug-Ins regulary after taking a look at QNEAT3 as @André Duarte suggested.

Answer (score 2):

For QGIS 3.X please check this page https://root676.github.io/. Is the new plugin for network analysis. 
You can find other GrassGis algoritms in processing toolbox.

Comment: The question asked about vehicle routing / location allocation but this plugin only supports distance / shortest path calculations. These types of calculations are used as an input to vehicle routing problem algorithms / location-allocation algorithms (e.g. p-median solver), however they're only really an input, the majority of the work still needs to be done. 

There are open source libraries etc for vehicle routing and location-allocation but not in QGIS that I'm aware of.

Comment: You are correct. In this case, we need to programming the algorithm . Pulp package and google optimization may be able to help. Thank you and I apologise for my mistake.

Comment: For vehicle routing, as you say Google optimisation covers it. The jsprit library also does vehicle routing as does Optaplanner. In my opinion jsprit is the most advanced solver of the 3 (I actually wrote a UI around jsprit). For location-allocation problems, there's an open source solver/app I wrote which solves some variants (I'm not going to risk placing a URL link or naming it here though - one of the admins has been systematically downvoting any answer I give referencing it...)